# Google Places Web API photos

Tags: django, google-api

I use Django-google-places extension to get a list of photos (place.photos).

But the list I get is very unpredictable - pictures of users, food, etc.
Does Google provide something to get place's main picture that represents cafe/restaurant better?

Or maybe there's a way to get the best picture from list?

Answer (score 0):

Place Search returns summary information about place. Maybe you can try to get photos from Place Search endpoint. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search.